# First order with value DK before D, then numeric portion of values using cases

Tags: sql, database

I need to order some values using the following rules:

- values starting with DK before D
- sort within those two groups alphabetically

So the values would look like:

- DK207
- D107
- DK107
- D099

And they want to end up with:

- DK107
- DK207
- D099
- D107

My current attempt:

```
select *
from customers
order by case
    WHEN substring(code,1,2) = 'DK' then substring(code,1,2)
    WHEN substring(code,1,1) = 'D' then substring(code,1)
END desc,
case
    WHEN substring(code,1,2) = 'DK' then substring(code,3)
    WHEN substring(code,1,1) = 'D' then substring(code,2)
END asc;
```

Which seems to work fine for the DK values, but messes up for the ones starting with the D.
They are grouped up correctly, but the ones with the D seem to be sorted descending.

Comment: Can you mention the RDBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `,1` where indicated.

Otherwise you're taking everything.

```
select *
from customers
order by case
    WHEN substring(code,1,2) = 'DK' then substring(code,1,2)
    WHEN substring(code,1,1) = 'D' then substring(code,1,1)    <----- Importanat change!!!
END desc,
case
    WHEN substring(code,1,2) = 'DK' then substring(code,3)
    WHEN substring(code,1,1) = 'D' then substring(code,2)
END asc;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d66ee/2)

Comment: Indeed, I copied the section when I first did the second portion and I guess I missed that bit.